# Have a procedure loop through an entire column of over 100,000 rows in SQL

Tags: sql, procedure

I have a query that will go through many tables that will add `count(*)` to create a percentage level of completion for an ID. The way it was written only lets you find the percentage for 1 ID at a time. I need to run this to get all the percentages for over 100,000 IDs.

I have tried to make the @ID have a value of many, but get the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have tried the union but as there are many values it seems like a waste. I also tried to rewrite the query , but as there are so many tables involved and room for error I do not want to go that route if there is a simpler way.

Below is a simpler version of what I am actually working with.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID = (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE date > 2018)

SELECT 
    @ID ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [BITFIELD] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_COMPLETED
FROM 
    Table
```

Data that I get :

```
 ID           is_complete
 -------------------------
 1                15
```

Data that I want:

```
ID           is_complete
------------------------
 1              15       
 2             100       
 3              20
```

Comment: Please share some sample data here so we can understand more clearly. Please also indent your code and formatted tables with 4 spaces (or highlight the block and click the `{}` in the editor) so the formatting is retained.

Comment: I'm not sure how your initial query is returning the correct data for ID = 1, as you're aggregating over the entire table, instead of just where ID = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do an aggregation on your table and `GROUP BY` the ID, like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [BITFIELD] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_COMPLETED
FROM Table
WHERE date > 2018
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to simply want `GROUP BY`.  But for a ratio/percentage, I recommend `AVG()`:

```
SELECT ID,
       AVG(CASE WHEN BITFIELD > 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS ratio_is_completed
FROM Table
WHERE date > 2018
GROUP BY ID
```